# External hard drive password 14.04

Tags: usb-drive

What's the easiest and quickest way to put a password on an external drive on Ubuntu 14.04? I've tried previous answers but none worked.

Comment: please list some of the "previous answer" methods you've already tried so you can get the best answer to your question more quickly.

Answer (score 2):

**Warning, the following involves formating the drive. Formatting will often erase files and saved contents so BACKUP the files BEFORE YOU START as this process may very well and probably will delete everything on the device!!!**

You can encrypt the device using the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cryptsetup gnome-disk-utility
```

Search for and open disk utility in your applications. Select your device under the Peripherial Devices section.

Click the <kbd>Unmount Volume</kbd> button. Then, click the  <kbd>Format Volume</kbd> button and enable "Encrypt underlying device".

**Again, formating will erase the device** so **check to make sure you’re formatting the correct drive and you’ve backed up its files before continuing!!!**

You will be asked to create a passphrase for the device and you will also have other options for the system to remember the password or not.

Source (click here for more info): [www.howtogeek.com/115955/how-to-quickly-encrypt-removable-storage-devices-with-ubuntu/](http://www.howtogeek.com/115955/how-to-quickly-encrypt-removable-storage-devices-with-ubuntu/)